# Is there a way to see if a string matches a dictionary key and if it is print its value? python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary :

```
name = {'San Francisco':'California', 'Boise':'Idaho',
        'Kansas City': 'Missouri', 'Miami':'Florida'}
```

I'm using regex to strip any numbers on the end of a city name (below) if that occurs. What I want is for let's say "Kansas City1" to be stripped of the '1' and then from there compare the stripped string to key in dictionary, once there is a match I would like it to return the value that is connected to the matched key.

This is my current code:

```
def abbrev(string):
   strip_string = re.sub(r'\d+', '', string)

   if(strip_string in name.keys()):
      initial = [value for value in name.values()][strip_string in name.keys()]
      return initial
   else:
      initial = string[:3]
      return initial

string = ("Kansas City1")
initial = abbrev(string) 
print(initial)
```

So if Kansas City1 should give Missouri, but the code is giving me Idaho for some reason.. and I don't know why. Could somebody help me figure this out?

Comment: If you’re a beginner at python it is IMO worth avoiding one liners like list comprehensions because they are impossible to debug. Simply write them out as for loops then you can print the intermediate values. Once you’re more confident then turn the working for loop into a comprehension (if it’s needed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fixed and cleaned up version of your code:

```
import re


def abbrev(string, names):
    strip_string = re.sub(r'\d', '', string)
    if strip_string in names:
        initial = names[strip_string]
    else:
        # Not sure what's the point of this?
        initial = string[:3]
    return initial


names = {'San Francisco': 'California',
         'Boise': 'Idaho',
         'Kansas City': 'Missouri',
         'Miami': 'Florida'}

string = "Kansas City1"
initial = abbrev(string, names) 
print(initial)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> Missouri
> ```

Your original:

```
if(strip_string in name.keys()):
    initial = [value for value in name.values()][strip_string in name.keys()]
```

really doesn't make a lot of sense. First you do some sensible checking in the if-block, but then instead of just accessing the element, you end up assigning `initial = List[str][bool]`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your dict reference:

```
  initial = [value for value in name.values()][strip_string in name.keys()]
```

Your first term is a newly-built list:

```
[value for value in name.values()]
```

Your index value is a Boolean:

```
                  [strip_string in name.keys()]
```

Let's look at this with some simple tracing code, printing each term:

```
if(strip_string in name.keys()):
    print ([value for value in name.values()])
    print ([strip_string in name.keys()])
    initial = [value for value in name.values()][strip_string in name.keys()]
    return initial
```

Output:

```
['Idaho', 'California', 'Florida', 'Missouri']
[True]
California
```

Your code very clearly says to build a list from the dict values, then report element `[1]` from that list.  You've gone to a lot of work to make sure you're getting something not necessarily related to your input.  Note that this will return the *same* value for *any* key that's in the dict.

Instead, you know the key: use it directly, as others have already included in their answers.

```
initial = name[strip_string]
```

Comment: @glhr Thanks; fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Just do `initial = name[strip_string]` instead of `[value for value in name.values()][strip_string in name.keys()]`.

You already know that `strip_string` is a valid key, why not use it to directly get the value you want?

```
import re

def abbrev(string):
    name = {'San Francisco': 'California', 'Boise': 'Idaho', 'Kansas City': 'Missouri', 'Miami': 'Florida'}

    #Remove the trailing digits from the string
    strip_string = re.sub(r'\d+', '', string)

    #If the key is present in the name, get the value
    if strip_string in name:
        initial =  name[strip_string]
    #Else get the first 3 characters of the input string
    else:
        initial = string[:3]

    return initial

string = ("Kansas City1")
initial = abbrev(string)
print(initial)
```

The output will be `Missouri`

Your original code was not working because of the following

The first part of your line `print([value for value in name.values()])` gives you `['California', 'Idaho', 'Missouri', 'Florida']` and the second part of your statement `[strip_string in name.keys()]` gives you `[True]`

```
print([value for value in name.values()])
#['California', 'Idaho', 'Missouri', 'Florida']
print([strip_string in name.keys()])
#[True]
```

Now `[True]` actually evaluates to 1 because `int(True)=1`, hence
`['California', 'Idaho', 'Missouri', 'Florida'][1]` gives you `Idaho`, because the second element of the list is `Idaho`

Comment: You can just do `if strip_string in name` instead of `if(strip_string in name.keys())`. Also, no need for duplicate return statements.